# NSMutableArray with custom objects?

Tags: objective-c

I have a custom class:

```
 @interface Player : NSObject {
   NSInteger mPlayerNo;
 }

 -(id) initWithNum:(NSInteger) playerNum;

 @implementation Player

 -(id) initWithNum:(NSInteger) playerNum
 {
   if(![super init])
   return nil; 
   ... 
   mPlayerNo=playerNum;
   return self;
 }

 @end
```

I need the array of the Player objects in the other programm class:

```
 @interface Spec : NSObject  {
    NSMutableArray * mPlayers;
    ...
  }
```

So, I am trying to fill mPlayers arr in the init method of the Spec class like this:

```
- (id)init {
   if(![super init])
      return nil; 
   NSMutableArray * _array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   mPlayers=_array;
   [_array release];
   Player * _player=[[[Player alloc] initWithNum:(NSInteger)1]autorelease];
   [mPlayers addObject:_player]; // crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

It doesn't work. But if I change

```
   NSMutableArray * _array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   mPlayers=_array;
   [_array release];
```

with

```
   mPlayers=[[NSMutableArray array]retain];
```

All works fine.
It is something strange for me. Please, help to understand the problem with alloc init.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're releasing your array before using it.

```
NSMutableArray * _array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //Retain count of 1

mPlayers=_array; //Still 1.
//Adding a new pointer to the same object doesn't affect the object's retain count.

[_array release]; //Now it's 0. Array is gone!
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   NSMutableArray * _array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   mPlayers=_array;
   [_array release];
```

Here you are creating an array, then immediately releasing it.   The +alloc implies a retain and you are balancing it by that release.

The assignment is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

If you assign the Array you created to `mPlayers`, this does not affect the retain count.
If you then call `release`, the retain count reaches zero and the object gets deallocated.

As a deeper understanding of this behaviour is essential for Objective-C development, you might want to have a look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW2) Apple provides